# Como solucionar error valueAsNumber

Tags: javascript

este es mi código funciona, pero el problema es que al presionar por primera vez cada elemento este sale el error null valueASNumber el tema que sucede, se crea el elemento
ya solucione los temas anteriores, el tema esque se me genero otro estaba intentando si es null la pues no haga nada y si no es null pues me haga todo el procedimiento pero no me ha funcionado
resumen de lo que se necesita
1 solucionar el error que sale en el codigo ejecutable valueASNumber null
{
Error "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'valueAsNumber')

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidadNuevo(input);
  
console.log(id,input);
}



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons)
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  
  
  
  
  
  function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  //const item = button.closest('.item');

 // const itemTitle = item.querySelector('.item-title').textContent;
  //const itemPrice = item.querySelector('.item-price').textContent;
  //const itemImage = item.querySelector('.item-image').src;
 
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;

  const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
  const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;
  const talla_ropa = item.querySelector('.talla_ropa').textContent;
  //const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;
  //const itemImage = item.querySelector('.item-image').src;

  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod, codigo, nombre, cantidad_disponible, talla,talla_ropa);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod, codigo, nombre,cantidad_disponible,talla,talla_ropa) {
    
//function addItemToShoppingCart(itemTitle, itemPrice, itemImage) {

//const elementsTitle = shoppingCartItemsContainer.getElementsByClassName(
    //'shoppingCartItemTitle'
  //);
  if(cantidad_disponible!=0){
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
      ////let elementQuantity = tbody.querySelector('.ItemCarrito>.table__cantidad>#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id_prod);
      ////const cantidad_disponible = parseInt(elementQuantity.getAttribute("max"));
     ////elementQuantity.value=cantidad_disponible
      // elementQuantity.value++;
      //console.log(elementQuantity.value)
      //mensaje exitoso
    //  updateShoppingCartTotal();
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);
// // //     <td class="table__productos">
         
// // //     <input type="text" id="id_productos" disabled style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;
// // // " name="id_productos" class="id_productos" value="${item.id}"></>
// // //       <h6 class="title" hidden>${item.id}</h6>
      
// // //       </td>
  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    <td class="table__codigo">
    <input id="codigo_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${codigo}" class="codigo"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

    <td class="table__nombre">
   <input id="nombre_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${nombre}" class="nombre"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
     
     </td>
    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__talla_ropa">
    <input id="talla_ropa_${id_prod}"  type="text" value="${talla_ropa}" class="talla_ropa"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>



    
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number"
                    value="1" min="1">
                <button class="btn btn-danger buttonDelete" type="button">X</button>
                </td>
        
     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
}else{
  console.log("tiene un 0 imposible agregar");
}
}


});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon.ico" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/carrito.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/paginador_buscador.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pagina.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/divalert.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">  

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }

</style>

</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

     






      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
        
           
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
               
                <td class="codigo">EAN_001  </td>
                <td class="nombre"> NIKE FORCE</td>
               <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
                              <td class="talla"> 36</td>
                              <td class="talla_ropa"> S</td>
                
                
        
              
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>

           
         
         </td>
            
        </tr> 
       
   
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
      </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">

            

            


      <form id="form2" action="javascript:habilitar()">
     

<input type="button" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" onchange="habilitar()" disabled />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
        
           
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
                <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
                <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>  
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
        
    
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
 

</body>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/paginador_buscador.js"></script>
<script>

    let options = {
        numberPerPage:1, //Cantidad de datos por pagina
        goBar:true, //Barra donde puedes digitar el numero de la pagina al que quiere ir
        pageCounter:true, //Contador de paginas, en cual estas, de cuantas paginas
    };
    let filterOptions = {
       el:'#searchBox'
  };
 
 paginate.init('.table',options,filterOptions);
</script> -->
<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>
<script src="../js/otro.js"></script>

<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, sin ser programador de javascript, me llama la atención la siguiente linea: **let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);** es correcta?, ese **+id** no está de más?.

Comment: Marce Puente no, ya que a este elemento en el html le paso el id del elemento del producto ya que sin el me alegaria por no ser inputs unicos al ser creados hacia al carrito,

Comment: Bueno, hoy me toca aprender!! gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos iniciar poniendo un controlador de nulos:

```
function add(id, cantidad = 1) {
    let input = document.querySelector("#shoppingCartItemQuantity_" + id);

    if (input === null) {
        // manejar error.
        console.log('No se logró encontrar el error');
        return;
    }

    if (typeof input.value === 'undefined' || input.value === null) {
        input.value = cantidad;
    } else {
        input.value = (input.valueAsNumber + cantidad);
        // podrias tratar también con
        // input.value = +input.value + cantidad;
        // input.value = +input.value + cantidad ?? cantidad;
    }

    updateCantidadNuevo(input);
    console.log(id, input);
}
```

Comment: Isaac, con esto bastaría segun tu? por lo menos ya no sale el error, muchas gracias